# What is a map of India doing at a US Army hospital?

Tags: plot-explanation, men-of-honor

In *Men of Honor (2000)*, we clearly see a map of India in this shot where Carl is admitted in hospital for an injured leg.

[image]

What is the purpose of the map of India here?

Comment: Because Indian map look awesome ;)

Answer (score 2):

My assumption is that they just wanted a map for the look and didn't expect anyone to really take that close a look at something that's on screen for maybe a handful of seconds.

Things like this happen quite often in movies, where they want something for a certain look but it has no real meaning otherwise.

I looked to see if perhaps the map had a tie into the incident where he lost his leg.  That incident coincides with [the 1966 Palomares B-52 crash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1966_Palomares_B-52_crash).  The location where he hurts is leg is in the Mediterranean Sea, which does not have any direct contact with India, so this leaves me to believe that they are not tied to each other.

Comment: I don't know how relevant this is. But India and Pakistan had a border war in 1965 and they had a peace agreement in January of 1966 in Moscow. Prime Minister LB Shastri died of a heart attack after the signing of the treaty.